# use the sed command guidance needed

Tags: linux, sed

This is my problem. Using sed remove only the first instance of a semicolon on each line and replace it with a dash (-)

Could someone please help me figure this out?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `s/,/-/g` .. The `g` means *globally*. Unless you specify it only the firt occurrence of the match will get replaced

Comment: Thank you. So what would be the full command?

Comment: `sed 's/,/-/g' input`

Comment: and my input would be something like /etc/passwd or whatever file I wanted to display?

Comment: @hek2mgl I think he only wants the first instance replaced, so you don't need `g`.

Comment: Thanks I can't seem to make it print. What would the input line be?

Comment: @MannyD Sure, you are right! MarcSetchell's answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this in a file called `file`

```
123;456;789;987;654;321
aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd;eee;fff
```

This command

```
sed 's/;/-/' file
```

will give you this

```
123-456;789;987;654;321
aaa-bbb;ccc;ddd;eee;fff
```

Comment: Hey there, I tried what you said but I can't seem to make it work. Could you tell me how to make that files exactly and execute the command exactly? thank you

Comment: Highlight the two lines above with your mouse and press Ctrl+C to copy. Click in your Terminal and type `cat > file` and press Return/Enter. Now paste with Ctrl+V and the two lines will appear. Now press Ctrl+D and you will have the file created. Then type the `sed` command and press Enter/Return. Hopefully that's it.